# Forcing HTTPS with Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I’m using Azure CDN in front of a Storage Account. I’m wanting to serve everything via HTTPS only, so I’ve setup HTTPS on the custom domain and created a URL rewrite:

[image: HTTPS rewrite rule]

But the problem is that I end up at a URL like this:
https://the-custom-domain/website/17/index.html

The `website/17/index.html` is the root content within the Storage Account, but I don’t know why it’s appending the container path before the filename. There’s also rewrite rule for static files (https://blog.lifeishao.com/2017/05/24/serving-your-static-sites-with-azure-blob-and-cdn).

Any idea what’s wrong with the URL rewrite?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am using Azure Verizon **Premium** CDN.

I did two rules. The order of the rules matter. You will need to wait up to 4 hours after each test.

image remove index.html 2 continue as image 3

[image]

[image]

===============   END FIRST RULE  ==================
[image]

[image]

here as text
1. redirect HTTP to HTTPs
rule--> (.*)   destination  https://%{host}/$1

2. remove remove index.html did not work 100% ;-( 
   URL Rewrite
   2.A  Source ((?:[^\?]*/)?)($|\?.*) -Destination  -> $1index.html$2
   2.B Source   ((?:[^\?]*/)?[^\?/.]+)($|\?.*)  -Destination  - > $1/index.html$2

Comment: This looks to only be available via Verizon Premium:


**HTTP to HTTPS redirection**
You can redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS. Doing so requires the use of the Azure CDN premium offering from Verizon


[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-https-custom-domain-cdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-https-custom-domain-cdn)

Answer (score 18):

There is an official guide from MS here, which works with standard Azure CDN:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine

Summary below:

**Redirect users to HTTPS**

- On the CDN profile page, select the endpoint you want to create rules for.
- Select the Rules Engine tab.
- Select Add rule and enter a rule name.
- To identify the type of requests the rule applies to, create a match condition:

  - Select Add condition, and then select the Request protocol match condition.
  - For Operator, select Equals.
  - For Value, select HTTP.
- Select the action to apply to the requests that satisfy the match condition:

  - Select Add action, and then select URL redirect.
  - For Type, select Found (302).
  - For Protocol, select HTTPS.
  - Leave all other fields blank to use incoming values.
- Select Save to save the new rule. The rule is now available to use.

Comment: I've created a complete tutorial for setting up your static website on Azure, which includes this and more, here: https://the.aamodt.family/rune/2020/01/08/tutorial-azure-website.html

Comment: This answer is gold, I was about to get the premiun service to get this thing to work. The only thing I am courius about is if this affects your SEO or AdRank on google?

Comment: Good question, unfortunately I'm not familiar with how this affects SEO.

Comment: thanks! I guess I need to do more research, I heard some time ago that 302 was not good for SEO, but investigating recently it seems that google not always take it as a bad thing. Your solution works awesome for what I need! thank you anyway.

Comment: well at first it didn't work
Had to change,
**"For Type, select Found (302)"**  -> **"Permanent redirect(308)"**
Voila, it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Azure Verizon Premium.

In this case you might want to redirect your http requests to your https endpoint. In this case you must add one rule for each endpoint you want this behavior:

```
  match condition:

    if Request Scheme = HTTP

  feature:

    Redirect - Code: 301, source: (.*), destination: https://%{host}/$1
```

This response was found at [docs microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-https-custom-domain-cdn)

Answer (score 5):

It's a lot simpler now
[image]

No need to enter anything to the hostname, path etc..

Make sure that you have turned on both HTTP and HTTPS in the Origin Settings
[image]

It should reflect within 10minutes

Comment: Yes, but this is the microsoft standard cdn. Verizon premium cdn has still the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I am using below configuration for redirecting any request to https

[image: http to https - Azure CDN]

IF

- Request Schema, HTTP

Feature

- URL Redirect
- Code: 301
- Source: (.*)
- Destination: `https://%{host}/$1`

Comment: can you tell me what is wrong wiith my config?  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ADN1O-oEhZ7CYcMNRZ-GYNx_OCmrEMDz/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple 1:1 http to https solution (without any unwanted) you should use following rule:

```
https://%{host}/%{request_uri#/}
```

IF

- Request Schema, HTTP

Feature

- URL Redirect
- Code: `301`
- Source: `(.*)`
- Destination: `https://%{host}/%{request_uri#/}`