# Azure CDN for Azure static website 301 redirection configuration

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I have a frontend website configured in Azure Blob storage, following the next article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain

I successfully configure this website to display with my custom domain:

https://www.example.com

I'm looking now how to configure proper 301 redirections for:

- http -> 301 -> https
- example.com -> 301 -> www.example.com

I read this section: https://www.itinsights.org/Static-Websites-with-Azure-Part-4/#HTTP-to-HTTPs-redirection

But from my azure portal I don't see any section where I can push this xml rule or how to configure redirection rules from the interface.

```
<rule id="1111111" platform="http-large" status="active" version="0" custid="XXXXX">
<description>HTTP to HTTPS</description>
<match.request-scheme value="http">
feature.url-redirect code="301" pattern="/XXXXXXX/staticwebsitede/(.*)" value="https://www.staticwebsite.de/$1" />
</match.request-scheme>
</rule>
```

**Edit**
Following the accepted answer I have contacted Azure support to see if a migration is possible.
For the redirection example.com to www.example.com I have used the web forwarding feature of my domain register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [that blog](https://www.itinsights.org/Static-Websites-with-Azure-Part-4/#HTTP-to-HTTPs-redirection), you need to choose the Azure CDN with the **Premium Verizon tier** to have the benefits of the [Verizon rules engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine).

For more details, you could [compare Azure CDN product features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-features). Currently, Azure CDN with Standard Microsoft tier also supports `URL redirect/rewrite` via using [standard rules engine](http://Standard%20rules%20engine).

Comment: How can I manage to change pricing tier? I contact the Azure support but I don't get an answer. I have acquired SSL certificate and my website is on production, how can I manage a migration without any downtime and without loosing the SSL certificate configured ?

Comment: As far an I know, you only could remove your CDN profile and recreate it with a new pricing tier. Then you can [map the temporary cdnverify subdomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain#map-the-temporary-cdnverify-subdomain) to avoid interruption while the DNS mapping occurs. However, I am not sure if it also needs some time to enable HTTPS for a custom domain, maybe there is a better method from MS support.

Comment: Ps, if the reply could help you in your original question, please conder accepting it.:)

Comment: Yes I will wait to get an answer ... I have enabled the web forwarding redirection in my domain name register. So if you type example.com you are redirecting to https : / / www.example.com. The remaining problem is if go to http : / / www.example.com

Comment: Try to check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731674/forcing-https-with-azure-cdn) SO answer could help you.